# 32-bit checksum of a file

Tags: c++, file, checksum

I have implemented a function to produce a 32-bit checksum of a file using the following method: `checksum = word_1 + word_2 + ... + word_n`, where `word_i` is the 32-bit words the file consists of.

Here are several questions I'm very interested about:

1. Is the way I read file word by word correct or there is a better way? (I aim not to read the whole file at once because it can be very large.)
2. Are there any problems with chosen data types such as uint32_t, unsigned and so on?
3. Have I got the right way to handle a file that isn't N*4 bytes in size? For example, for 7 bytes file I'm just setting 0-8 bits into 0 to avoid using an accidental value. Or I should set 24-31 bits into 0?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
void execute(std::ifstream& file) 
{
    const size_t WORD_SIZE = sizeof(uint32_t);

    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    auto sizeInBytes = file.tellg();

    file.seekg(0);
    uint32_t checksum = 0U; // ???
    if(auto sizeInEntireWords = sizeInBytes / WORD_SIZE)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeInEntireWords; i++)
        {
            uint32_t word;
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word), WORD_SIZE); // ???
            checksum += word;
        }
    }

    if(auto additionalSizeInBytes = sizeInBytes % WORD_SIZE)
    {
        uint32_t word;
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word), WORD_SIZE);
        word &= (~0U << (WORD_SIZE - additionalSizeInBytes * 8)); // ???
        checksum += word;
    }

    cout << checksum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure assigning inside an `if` is not a bug in `if(auto sizeInEntireWords = sizeInBytes / WORD_SIZE)`?

Comment: @Caridorc, yes, it's possible. I've read about it in Stroustrup's book. More over it's cool on account of the variable (sizeInEntireWords) being more localized: it's only available in -f-{} and its else-{}.

Comment: If assignment fails the condition is `false` right?

Comment: sizeInEntireWords is created here and, if its value equals 0, it's converted into false. Otherwise it's converted into true.

Comment: `if(size_t i = container.size()) 
{ 
   cout << "We're here if container is NOT empty and can use i that is != 0"; 
} 
else 
{ 
   cout << "We're here if container is empty and can use i that is == 0"; 
} 
// but i is not available here`

Comment: @Caridorc, thanks) Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition (2013), page 232, Statements, Chapter 9: 9.4.3 Declarations in Conditions

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your checksum function should probably be named `checksum` and actually return the checksum, rather than simply printing it.

Now, you're not taking advantage of what the [`std::basic_ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) API actually gives you. First, [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) returns a `basic_istream&`, which is convertible to bool. That bool tells you if the complete read succeeded or not. So all you have to do is:

```
uint32_t checksum(std::ifstream& file) 
{
    uint32_t sum = 0;

    uint32_t word = 0;
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word), sizeof(word))) {
        sum += word;
    }

    // ??
```

Now, when `read()` fails, that means our file has run out (assuming we had a valid file to begin with). But, we have other information. There is also [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) which

> Returns the number of characters extracted by the last unformatted input operation.

If the read partially succeeded, we can mask off the other bytes and add the remainder. Thus, the full solution might be:

```
uint32_t checksum(std::ifstream& file) 
{
    uint32_t sum = 0;

    uint32_t word = 0;
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word), sizeof(word))) {
        sum += word;
    }

    if (file.gcount()) {
        word &= (~0U >> ((sizeof(uint32_t) - file.gcount()) * 8));
        sum += word;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Doing the masking looks kind of terrible though, so instead we could simply zero out `word` every time so we can just add the result:

```
uint32_t checksum(std::ifstream& file) 
{
    uint32_t sum = 0;

    uint32_t word = 0;
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&word), sizeof(word))) {
        sum += word;
        word = 0;
    }

    sum += word; // add the last word, could be 0
                 // if the file size is divisible by 4

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not completely understand if the last example correctly handles last 1 or 2 or 3 bytes, for example. They are read into 4-byte word. So there might be accident value? Let file be of 7 bytes. The loop will be executed 2 times, right? Will the second word fully determined in the case?

Comment: Thanks! And one more question please: (assuming the file is of 7 bytes) the second 32-bit word will consist of 3 bytes read from file and what is with 1 more byte? Will it be 0000 0000? So the last word will be 0000 0000 **** **** **** **** **** ****, where *'s are 3 read bytes representation? I'm scared of some rubbish in the last word:) It's important to be strongly determined in case of file size not devisible by 4.

Comment: Yes, It seems that if a word is set into 0 before new reading, while we read 3 last bytes, we rewrite younger 3 bytes of the word. The oldest byte is still consists of 0s?

Comment: I think this invokes UB in the case of an integer overflow

Comment: @Weston Unsigned integer overflow is not UB, it wraps.

Comment: Ah ok. I was thinking of signed overflow, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4):

- **Portability**

  The same file checksums differently depending on platform endianess. Fix it by `word = htonl(word);` after reading.
- **Algorithm**

  I hope you understand that such checksum is useless to say the least.

Answer (score 4):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Use better names

The name `execute` is too generic and not at all suggestive of the purpose of the function.  The obvious choice would be `checksum` of course.  It seems like a small point, but choosing good names makes a very big difference in how easy (or not!) it is to read, understand, and modify the code.

### Return something useful

Instead of declaring this as a `void` function, it would make much more sense to declare it as `uint32_t` and to return the actual checksum value.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  I don't know that you've actually done that, (you might have used the slightly more enlightened `using std::cout;`) but it's an alarmingly common thing for new C++ programmers to do.

### Be aware of endianness problems

As pointed out by @vnp, this will calculate different results on machines with a different [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The simple way to address that would be to read byte (uint8_t) at a time and create your own `uint32_t` in portable fashion.

### Consider a better algorithm

For only very slightly more complexity, you can get a much better result by using either a [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) or a [cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).  Either would provide detection of, say, swapped words, which this algorithm cannot.

### Putting it together

```
uint32_t checksum(std::ifstream& file) 
{
    uint32_t checksum = 0;
    unsigned shift = 0;
    for (uint32_t ch = file.get(); file; ch = file.get()) {
        checksum += (ch << shift);
        shift += 8;
        if (shift == 32) {
            shift = 0;
        }
    }
    return checksum;
}
```

This calculates the sum as little-endian on any machine and returns that value in the native representation of the machine on which it runs.